# Turning IEnumerable of struct with inner IEnumerable into single dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I an `IEnumerable<MyStruct>` and `MyStruct` looks as follows:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public IEnumerable<string> aliases;
    public Action action;
    public MyStruct(IEnumerable<string> aliases, Action action)
    {
        this.aliases = aliases;
        this.action = action;
    }
}
```

I want to turn this into a dictionary where the key would be each string from the `aliases` and the value would be the `action`. For example, if I have two `MyStruct` objects in my `IEnumerable`, the first has aliases `"o", "on", "one"` and action `a1` and the second has aliases `"t", "tw", "two"` and action `a2`, I want the result dictionary to look like this:

```
    {"o",   a1},
    {"on",  a1},
    {"one", a1},
    {"t",   a2},
    {"tw",  a2},
    {"two", a2}
```

I was wondering whether there is any way do this in Linq?

Comment: Obligatory comment ensuring that you actually need a value type here rather than a class?

Comment: Yes, this probably should be changed to a class. But I'm trying to figure out the Linq part currently. Thanks for the heads up though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the lists of aliases and create a temporary anonymous type containing an alias and the action. Finally convert this flatten list `ToDictionary`:

```
IEnumerable<MyStruct> source = ...
Dictionary<string, Action> result = 
    source.SelectMany(s => s.aliases, (s, alias) => new { Alias = alias, s.action })
          .ToDictionary(x => x.Alias, x => x.action);
```

The first argument to `SelectMany` tells it to select the `aliases`, so the second lambda is called for each `MyStruct s` and each `string alias` of that `MyStruct` and creates an instance out of these two values.

Finally this sequence is turned into a dictionary using the `alias` as key and the `action` as value.

Note that this raises an `ArgumentException` if the aliases are not unique, because you cannot add the same *key* to the dictionary twice.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Works just as expected, thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 2):

Linq syntax to flatten the data, then ToDictionary on that.
You can use "SelectMany" to flatten the data either.

```
private Dictionary<string, action> FlattenedStructs(IEnumerable<MyStruct> structs)
{
    var flattenedItems = from s in structs 
                         from a in s.aliases
                         select new {Alias = a, Action = s.action};
    return flattenedItems.ToDictionary(f => k.Alias, f => f.Action);
}
```

Comment: A very simple and neat version, kudos